# WSO2 dashboard user password change issue

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2 IS 5.0.0 installed. I am able to change user's passwords through the admin console. However, when user's tried to change their passwords through the /dashboard application. It does not work. Even though UI does not show any errors, following stack trace appears in the logs.

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-02-19 10:51:21,122]  INFO {JAGGERY.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.wsUtil:jag} -  JSESSIONID=E6F5DCA84FC09E7795F627C5C0C8CD06; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly {JAGGERY.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.wsUtil:jag}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-02-19 10:51:21,152]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2015-02-19 10:51:21,0152] from IP address 127.0.0.1 while trying to authenticate access to service UserAdmin {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-02-19 10:51:21,164]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:311)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.fireAndForget(ServiceClient.java:511)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.fireAndForget(ServiceClient.java:488)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:360)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.c0._c_call_1(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/wsUtil.jag:28)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.c0._c_callWSInOnly_2(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/wsUtil.jag:39)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c1._c_changeCredential_1(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/userAdminClient.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c1.call(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/userAdminClient.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c0._c_edit_1(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/edit.jag:34)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/edit.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c0._c_script_0(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/edit.jag:51)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/edit.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/edit.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.pwd_change.controllers.pwd_change.c0.exec(/portal/gadgets/pwd_change/controllers/pwd_change/edit.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:435)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I also realized dashboard does not really give any warnings about the errors. I enter a completely bogus old password and it still acts like it changed the password. I can't even find stack traces in the logs. What s going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Service Pack 1 for the Identity Server ?